# python 3.5.3 kivy error

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am developing a small app in python using Kivy for the GUI. So far I have been working with Pycharm and 3.4.3 which works just fine. I have had to upgrade to 3.5.3 and now when I run the script it fails with the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/event.py", line 8, in <module>
import kivy._event
ImportError: No module named 'kivy._event'
```

Is this a python 3.5.3 kivy 1.9.1 compatibility problem?

Comment: Something is wrong. Have you installed Kivy on 3.5? I just tested and the module can be imported without problems in **Kivy 1.9.1 / Python 3.5.3** and  **Kivy 1.10.0 / Python3.6.1**

Comment: Your Kivy is not compiled properly for this version of python. You probably want to reinstall it, however you installed it in the first place.

Comment: I think this is going to come down to an installation/path problem if there are no known compat. issues. I'll try un-install and re-install and post if it fixes.